# Display bug in Dataset's UnitConvert handling

Tags: bugs, dataset, units

**Bug introduced in 11.0.1 or earlier and fixed in 11.1.0**

Is this yet another annoying regression in v11 `Dataset` type handling? The display form seems to be a formatting bug:

The numerator and denominator of integer-magnitude `Quantities` appear string joined:

```
Dataset[<|"a" -> Quantity[12, "Seconds"],  "b" -> Quantity[34, "Seconds"]|>] // Query[All, UnitConvert[#, "Minutes"] &]
```

[image]

These should really be 1/5 and 17/30 minutes. Doesn't affect `Association` or real-valued magnitudes, ie these work:

```
Dataset[<|"a" -> Quantity[12, "Seconds"], 
    "b" -> Quantity[34, "Seconds"]|>] // Normal // 
 Query[All, UnitConvert[#, "Minutes"] &]
```

And

```
Dataset[<|"a" -> Quantity[12., "Seconds"], 
   "b" -> Quantity[34., "Seconds"]|>] // 
 Query[All, UnitConvert[#, "Minutes"] &]
```

gives 0.2 and 0.566667 min.

Is this resolved in 11.1 pre?

Comment: I can confirm that the bug has been fixed in MMA 11.1.0

Comment: @user58955, works, thanks for the update.

Answer (score 5):

I do not know if this defect is fixed in any prerelease builds of version 11.1, but I can offer a couple of work-arounds.

**Diagnosis (current for version 11.0.1)**

Here is a  minimal reproduction of this bug:

```
Quantity[1/2, "Meters"] // Dataset
```

[image: defect screenshot]

Tracing reveals that the bug lies in the following function:

```
TypeSystem`NestedGrid`PackagePrivate`qbox[Quantity[1/2, "Meters"]]

(* RowBox[{"12", "\"m\""}] *)
```

... or alternatively another function which it invokes:

```
TypeSystem`NestedGrid`PackagePrivate`fixnum[FractionBox["1", "2"]]

(* "12" *)
```

**Workarounds**

We can revert to the old dataset styling which does not exhibit the problem:

```
Dataset`$UseNewDatasetFormatting = False;
Quantity[1/2, "Meters"] // Dataset
```

[image: old styling]

Or, we could apply an unsanctioned and unsupported patch to one of the errant functions.  I chose to patch `fixnum` because it was simpler:

```
PrependTo[
  DownValues @ TypeSystem`NestedGrid`PackagePrivate`fixnum
, HoldPattern[
    TypeSystem`NestedGrid`PackagePrivate`fixnum[TypeSystem`NestedGrid`PackagePrivate`e_FractionBox]
  ] :>  TypeSystem`NestedGrid`PackagePrivate`e
]
```

... which yields:

```
Dataset`$UseNewDatasetFormatting = True;
Quantity[1/2, "Meters"] // Dataset
```

[image: patched rendering]

```
Dataset[<|"a"->Quantity[12,"Seconds"],"b"->Quantity[34,"Seconds"]|>] //
  Query[All,UnitConvert[#,"Minutes"]&]
```

[image: original expression result with patch]